# How to scroll in an element using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium

I've been searching for a while to find a way to scroll in an element using selenium. I'm already able to scroll up and down the web page, but I haven't found a way to use the scroll bar inside an element. I was wondering if anyone else knew how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `execute_script`, for example, if we go to a random pastebin link (https://pastebin.com/en0f652r) and use the code below, it will scroll down the pasted code window.

```
driver.execute_script("$('#paste_code').animate({scrollTop: '100px'})")
```

Replace "#paste_code" with the scroll bar element you are wishing to scroll.

Comment: Just to clarify because I found this a little confusing until I did some investigation. the "$('#paste_code') part of that line is the name of the element that you want to scroll through.